# UIDocumentInteractionController show only Instagram in the application

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to share photo from my iOS app to instagram app using UIDocumentInteractionController and I want to show only instagram app in popover. As instagram describe [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) it's possible but it not works for me, I don't know what I am missing.

Below is screenshot of instagram, that confirms it's possible.

[image]

Below is the code I am using for this.

```
@IBAction func sharePhoto(btn: UIButton) {

    let photoBundlePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Photo", withExtension: ".png")
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: photoBundlePath!)
        let fileSavedPath = saveFile(data: data, name: "photo", fileExtension: ".igo")

        let instagramUrl = URL(string: "instagram://app")
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramUrl!) {
            ic = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: fileSavedPath)
            ic.delegate = self
            ic.uti = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
            ic.presentOptionsMenu(from: btn.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
            ic.annotation = ["InstagramCaption" : "Testing"]
        } else {
            print("Instagram is not present in your device")
        }
    } catch  {
        print(error)
    }
}



    func saveFile(data: Data, name: String, fileExtension: String) -> URL {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = paths[0]
    let fullPath = documentDirectory + "/" + name + fileExtension

    fileManager.createFile(atPath: fullPath, contents: data, attributes: nil)

    return URL(fileURLWithPath: fullPath)

}
```

- One more thing here is why Instagram is shown with text "**Copy to**" as one can see in below image.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Did you get any solution for this question?